# How to update after a rollback in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, deployment, heroku

If you do a rollback in Heroku it will checkout a previous commit on the Heroku side. We know that. However, how do you restore it to the HEAD commit?

It seems that you actually have to modify your local HEAD, and then push to the repository. Otherwise,

```
$ git push git@heroku.com:appname.git HEAD:master
Everything up-to-date
```

and nothing happens, i.e. no new release is created.

The easy solution is just to do some innocuous change like a `bundle install`, commit, and push. But I was hoping to find someway to bring apps up to the HEAD if they weren't before. Any insight? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a rollback, you're creating a new deployment to an older change #. The other version is still out there in git. So to go "forward" to the newer change, you'd roll back again, this time to the deployment at that hash number.